# Windows Automated Explicit Logon Rule to detect Lateral movement

Tags: windows, account-security

I am referring to https://community.rsa.com/docs/DOC-54594 to work to detect Windows Lateral Movement Detection. There is a rule regarding Correlation Rule: Windows Automated Explicit Logon. It states the threshold count should be greater than 9. Is it compulsory? Doesn't even one automated logon entry raise a concern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are right, you'd want to log some of these all the time. 7045 seems to jump out to me. In comparison, this is the splunk rule:

```
index=windows   LogName=System  EventCode=7045  NOT 
(Service_Name=tenable_mw_scan)  |   eval
Message=split(Message,".")  |   eval
Short_Message=mvindex(Message,0)        
|   table   _Ome    host    Service_Name,   Service_Type,   Service_Start_Type, 
Service_Account,    Short_Message
```

reference: https://conf.splunk.com/session/2015/conf2015_MGough_MalwareArchaelogy_SecurityCompliance_FindingAdvnacedAttacksAnd.pdf